# Is there a way to print a string on the different columns near a drop down row cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image: Excel File template]

So i want to choose say "air" on a2, and then i want "fill" being written on c2 and e2 only. But if i choose "ocean" i want "fill" to be written on d2 only.

Can this be done in excel?

Comment: Yes, you need nested `IF()` function to `B2:E4` cells.

Answer (score 2):

Formulas to cells

```
C2=IF(A2="Air","Fill","")
D2=IF(A2="Ocean","Fill","")
E2=IF(A2="Air","Fill","")
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, is it also possible to change the color of that particular cell with the "fill" text?

Comment: @HarshSharma Then you have to use conditional formatting. Use custom formula to conditional formatting`=A1="Fill"`